# Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined gets triggered in child component from parent

Tags: angular

```
Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.onClick
```

app-login component ts file where I mark the form as untouched when the click happens outside the component.

```js
@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;

       @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
            onClick(targetElement) {
                const clickedInside = this.container.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
                if (!clickedInside && this.loginForm.touched) {
                   this.loginForm.markAsUntouched();
                }
            }
    }
```

app-login html

```js
 <form method="get" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #container>
<div id="tab-1" class="log-tab-content current">
  <div class="login-form">
```

Parent component (The error message is shown on the console when I am on the parent component page). It has selector of app-login and local reference #priceTabClick
I have app-login in other components also but only in component it shows the error because of the click.

```html
    <ul class="log-tabs">
      <li id="logintab" class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Sign In</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Register</li>
    </ul>
    <app-login [planId]="planId" [serviceType]="serviceType"></app-login>
  </div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active wow fadeInRight"><a href="#Section1" data-toggle="tab">COMPARE PLANS</a></li>
    <li class="wow fadeInLeft"><a #priceTabClick href="#Section3" data-toggle="tab">PRICE CALCULATOR</a></li>
  </ul>
```

How I trigger the click ( #priceTabClick ). The click happens on ngOnInit()

```js
    @ViewChild('priceTabClick') priceTabClick: ElementRef;

    this.priceTabClick.nativeElement.click(); //The error goes away if I remove this line but I need the click. Manually clicking that li a link doesn't show any error.
```

Update.
If i trigger the click in ngAfterViewInit instead of onInit the error goes away but I then get a new error for planId Property which I am also sending to the child component app-login. The function that is called to trigger the click also has the code to change planId's value. `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked previous value 0 current value planId=2;`

Comment: The loginForm in the `app-login component` is undefined.

Comment: can you share parent component file